# how to move face along an axis without affecting other faces?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces, extrude, axis

I'm learning Blender and i face this issue that i can't figure out:

I have this isometric shape:
[image: building]

I was trying to move this face on red x-axis:
[image: moving face]

And this what happened, actually this is what i want to do , it's kind of a mix between extrude and move:
[image: the right move]

But when i tried to do the same thing to the left side, this is what happened, it's moving all the connected faces as well:
[image: the problem]

I noticed that if i merge all vertices by distance i cant move the face as i wanted anymore.

This is how the face looks when moving it before i merged the vertices "what i want".
[image: before i merged vertices]

Is there any way around this, or a un-merge vertices option!

===============================================================

Edit :

This is what i'm trying to do, if you have good method to model it:

[image: final]

This way still has some issues , I know I can fill missing edges but later on I might be missing lot of faces :

[image: issues]

Comment: have extruded the second face you're talking about? It looks like not. Also, it's not the good way to model your wall, because you'll have the face of the bottom of your extrusion that will stick to the face underneath. You need to create an edge on the base wall...

Comment: I did not use extrude at all for both sides . i only selected the face and moved it along axis. 
you are right its not good way .. i found out that i cant merge the face underneath the wall with other faces, i thought there is a way to remove it automatically. now im stuck . what im trying to do is making this wall look like a "winner stand" 3 level of height.

Comment: you did extrude the first face

Comment: i added a cube and used the bevel tool. 
then i inserted a face and extruded it down 1 meter to create the small wall.
i used extrude up on the angular wall which gave me the both side that im moving. 
for some reason one side has all vertices connected and other is not !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each edge is defined by 2 vertices, and each face is defined by at least 3 vertices. On the screenshot below, moving selected face is moving 4 vertices it is defined by. Since this face shares 1 vertex with the edge marked as (1) and 1 vertex with the edge marked as (2), moving this face, will warp those edges, because you will move half of the vertices defined by them:

[image]

You can see which edges a vertex is a part of, by selecting it, and looking for gradient lines:

[image]

If, while having the same face selected as on pic. 1, you right-click and choose *Split*, then the vertices of the selection will be duplicated, without any connections to vertices outside of the selection. Selecting a vertex again should make the difference obvious:

[image]

Selecting all duplicates (or just everything), pressing <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, will merge the vertices, by removing all but one vertex at each spot and moving all links of those vertices to that one.

However, you probably never used *Split*. What you did use was *Extrude*, which takes a face **A** and duplicates it to face **B**, but also (unlike *Split*) for each vertex of face **B** it creates a link to the original vertex it duplicated in face **A** (as well as it creates faces between edges created this way). Then the new face is being moved along its normal. And what you probably did was *Extrude*, but then right-click, leaving the new face in the same spot as the old one, but no longer directly connected to edges (1) and (2) on the first picture. This is why you could move that face without warping those edges, and this is why so many people advised to simply extrude the other face - **if you want to keep the consistency with the other face**, but it is not the correct way to build "proper" topology.

**Moving the original face:**

[image]

**Extruding the original face:**

[image]

**Extruding the original face, but right-clicking to leave it at original coordinates; deselecting it, selecting it and then moving it:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the top bar there will be two orientation parameters when you click the MOVE tool. The first should be "default", make the second one "Normal" from the drop down menu. Move your face now in the desired direction.

Comment: I tried, and I found that it only controls the direction of the move tool.
what I m trying to do is split edge and extrude the face then rejoin them and remove doubles. that was the plan.
but even with more search and videos i cant understand how to create simple building.
i m new to blender, can you please confirm these blender limitation that i found after long search :
- cant remove overlapping faces with different length.
- cant cut single face by a distance from a vertices or edge.
- cant intersect an edge with a face.

Answer (score 0):

Just add more edge loop where you want to extrude .

[image]